# Cannot read property 'getAllProducts' of undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express, typeorm

The problem is in `db.js` because it's trying to load something from db which does not exist.

In my `index.js` page:

```
const dataB = require("./db").getAllProducts;
app.get('/scrapper', async (req, res) => {
    const Myobjects = await dataB.getAllProducts();
    res.send(Myobjects)
})
```

And in my `db.js` page:

```
async function getAllProducts() {
    const connection = await getConnection();
    const pageRepo = connection.getRepository(Crawlers);
    const pages = await pageRepo.find();
    connection.close();
    return pages;
}

async function InsertScrappedData(texte, image, price){
    const connection = await getConnection();
    const page = new Crawler();
    page.texte = texte;
    page.image = image; 
    page.price = price;

    const crawlertrepo=connection.getRepository(Crawlers);
    const res=await crawlertrepo.save(Crawlers);
    Console.log('saved',res);

    const Allpages = await crawlertrepo.find();
    connection.close();
    return Allpages;
}
```

Exporting my functions

```
module.exports = [
    getAllProducts,
    InsertScrappedData 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`module.exports` is an object type, not an array, so you need to use curly brackets when assigning it.

```
module.exports = {
        getAllProducts,
        InsertScrappedData 
}
```

[Relevant documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports)

This is actually a condensed form of assigning the `getAllProducts` function to the `getAllProducts` key of a new object and then assigning that object to `module.exports`

```
// Equivalent but unnecessarily verbose
module.exports = {
        getAllProducts: getAllProducts,
        InsertScrappedData: InsertScrappedData 
}
```